# I am not able to increment string contains integer value?

Tags: ruby

how to increment last string based on last integer ?For eg."foo" = "f001",
"foo9" = "foo10", "foo99" = "foo100","foo001" = "foo002"

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean but it looks like you will have to parse the integer out of the string, do the logic and then reconstruct the string somehow.

Comment: yes i want to reconstruct the string after the increment of integer that is present in last as you can see in example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this...

```
def increment_string(string)
  old_digits = string.scan(/\d+$/).first || ''
  string.sub(/\d+$/,'') + (old_digits.to_i+1).to_s.rjust(old_digits.size, '0')
end

p increment_string("beep")
=> "beep1"

p increment_string("beep5")
=> "beep6"

p increment_string("beep99")
=> "beep100"

p increment_string("beep004")
=> "beep005"
```